# Issue with scope in d3.text function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, d3.js

I'm using d3.text function to read .txt files. I can work with the value read inside the function. But, if I put the value read in a variable declared outside the function, this variable becomes undefined immediately after the end of the function.

```
var fileString;
d3.text("articles/0.txt", function(error, text) {
    fileString = text;
    console.log(fileString); //Print the correct String
});
console.log(fileString); //Print undefined
```

How do I preserve the value of the variable after the function finishes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable keeps the value you assign within the function even after the function is executed since the variable is defined in the outer scope.

Your example prints *undefined* because the function is probably not executed yet (because it is a callback function and the text file is being loaded asynchronously) when you print the value of the variable. So it prints *undefined*.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand the problem. So, I need to read a great number of .txt files and put the strings read in a list. What is the better way to do that?

Comment: what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Well, I have more than 800 .txt files with data (date, title and content). I need to do some manipulation (create groups based on the date of the file) before create the visualization. So, I want to load all the files before using them and save them in a list. There's a way to do that?

Comment: You should do a batch and load all of them at once otherwise it would be a bad way and it would probably going to load a long time...

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that.